# How do I split an single file Angular module into client, server, and shared files?

Tags: angular, web

In a `dotnet-cli` scaffolded Angular 4 project, the module artefact is divided into three files, one each for shared, server, and client and named as such: `<modulename>.ts.shared`, `<modulename>.ts.server`, and `<modulename>.ts.client`. In a mainstream, de facto, Angular application, we normally just have the one `<modulename>.ts`.

I have been able to guess, often correctly, what should go into which file. I have had good results already by just looking at the content of the module as 3 files in a `dotnet-cli` scaffolded project.

Yet I would still prefer to understand the pattern used to determine the content of each file. Then, indeed, I would very much like to learn how to start with 3 files from scratch.

Comment: Can you provide a link, how to setup your dotnet-cli project? When I search for dotnet-cli I'm getting Core Command Line Tools for dotnet.

Comment: @Myonara Yes. There is a set of templates that you install that lets the dotnet-cli scaffold an Angular 4 project.

Comment: Did you find any contribution useful? I look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this is a partial answer.
Still, I expect it to be useful, whichis the main objective of SO.

**I would very much like to learn how to start with 3 files from scratch.**

You might get a templated version of the split files, as mentioned [in an MSDN forum](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103#c636364117782474085):

> The current version of template has changed as it now splits app.module into server, client and shared.

(I cannot do it in my current system).

**Yet I would still prefer to understand the pattern used to determine the content of each file.**

A reference is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551277/asp-net-core-angular-template-app-module-client-vs-app-module-server) to splitting into `client` and `server` files, which is similar to your case but not the same.
In all earnest, I do not know the rationale behind the splitting.

Comment: Your first link points to resource not from stackoverflow.com. This answer may not be meaningful if the target link is invalidated in future. You should also mention main ideas discussed in the external link here for that case.

Comment: @KiranShakya - Fair comment. I think I addressed it, consistent with the available information.